# How to change the Property="Style" in trigger

Tags: wpf, staticresource, wpf-style

Trigger is not working. IsMouseOver is not changing style of the Button. I am not sure what is wrong with my code. I am trying to change the style property of the button on mouse over property. It keeps throwing error.

Basically I am trying to use different style on mouse over event

```
 <Style x:Key="FancyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding FontSize}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding FontWeight}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Width}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="White" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="DarkGray" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.6" Color="Black" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FancyButtonInvertStyle}"/>
                         </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="FancyButtonInvertStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding FontSize}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding FontWeight}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Width}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Black" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.4" Color="DarkGray" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.6" Color="White" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to change the `Style` in the `Trigger`, change the `Background` directly in it. Keeps you also from repeating the `Style` completely over again.

```
<Style x:Key="FancyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding FontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Foreground}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding FontWeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Width}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="White" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="DarkGray" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.6" Color="Black" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Black" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.4" Color="DarkGray" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.6" Color="White" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I'm not sure if you even can change the `Style` of itself in the `Trigger` the way you intend to, because it is not set via a `Setter` Tag in the target control itself.